# Inserir um Splashscreen ou imagemView em app crosswalk webview

Tags: java, android, mobile, crosswalk

Eu tenho um aplicação em webview crosswalk.
como o meu site demora cerca de 5 segundos para abrir na tela,
eu pensei em inserir um splashscreen ou imagemview ( eu não sei se tem diferença entre os dois - estou iniciando ainda ) e deixar ele aparecendo por 5 segundos na tela.

Eu vi por ai também pessoas inserindo o splashscreen ou imagemview na tela inicial e ela desaparece quando a página está carregada.

ambas as soluções seria ótimo , mas eu não consigo fazer isso.

abaixo vou deixar o meu código.

MaindActivity.java

```html
package com.ovortex.myapplication;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import org.xwalk.core.XWalkActivity;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;

public class MainActivity extends XWalkActivity {



    private XWalkView xWalkWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        xWalkWebView=(XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {//<----verifica se o dipositivo é api 19 / Android 4.4

            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(

                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION

                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN

                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // esconde a barra de status
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onXWalkReady() {
        // carregar uma url local
        xWalkWebView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxx.com");
    }


}
```

activity.main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ovortex.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
        android:id="@+id/xwalkWebView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ovortex.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: E que no fim de fazer uma android app pergunta a pergunta vai dar créditos?
Castanhadas a parte, se quer ajuda coloque o código, StackOverflow em Português é diferente do StackOverflow em inglês.

Comment: @PedroFerreira editei a pergunta e coloquei o codigo dentro.

Comment: É necessário reescrever bastante, não deve tentar iniciar duas activity ao mesmo tempo, uma solução possível seria utilizar fragments, é simples iniciar dois fragments simultâneamente sendo que apenas o SplashFragment estará visível com um Handle.Delayed a chamar um método da activity que realizará o fecho do SplashFragment e colocará visível o fragment com o Crosswalk Webview. 
Mas não estamos a falar de resolver um bug, mas reescrever quase do zero dai o meu -1 a pergunta.

Comment: Como nota a parte, com tantas API's e tecnologia disponível, pensar numa mobile app como apenas um browser para um site pesado é de loucos e não têm em consideração o plano de dados do utilizador.

Comment: Acredito que a solução para seu problema seja deixar tudo em uma Activity somente, e ocultar a view da splashscreen quando o site estiver carregado. Não é a melhor solução, diga-se de passagem, mas use um FrameLayout com uma view ocultando toda a activity por último. Ao finalizar o carregamento, oculte essa view e está feito. Mas mesmo dando essa solução, dê uma lida nos conceitos de fragment e de Aplicações híbridas desenhadas de outro jeito, pode te ajudar em outra situação. Eu mesmo tive uma que o cliente queria somente uma camada por cima do site como app e teve de ser assim como o seu.

Comment: @grupo CDs informática podes me dar um norte como fazer ? Sabes aonde posso encontrar um tutorial ?

Comment: Vou comentar como resposta pra você ;)

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática  eu Editei a pergunta para melhor compreensão.

Comment: @PedroFerreira eu editei a pergunta com mais clareza, sobre a sua opnião sobre dados dos usuários - meu público vai ser pessoas que escutam músicas no Youtube pelo celular. 

então vai ser trocar seis por meia dúzia digamos, porém o meu app vai ter uma organização maior e clean. 

vlw man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo, você deve ter somente a MainActivity. O layout dela vai ser a seguinte:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            >

            <org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
                android:id="@+id/xwalkWebView"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                >

            </org.xwalk.core.XWalkView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/splash">

        <!--Aqui vai qualquer elemento da sua splash, ou tema -->

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Depois na sua MainActivity, o que você vai fazer: Assim que carregar o site, você vai ocultar a view da splash, mais especificamente neste pedaço (me corrija se eu estiver errado, nunca usei XWalk blzz)

```
mWebview.setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(mWebview){
        public void onProgressChanged(XWalkView view, int progress) {
            if (progress == 100) {
                findViewById(R.id.splash).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Testa e me dá um feedback.

Comment: Cds informatica eu vou fazer aqui o teste, a ideia é enquanto o splash é visualizado a url é carregada em segundo plano. 

assim quando o splash terminar de carregar no tempo configurado, o site ja vai esta carregado quando o splash sair da tela. 

vou testar aqui e ja te passo o feedback